# Acceptance tests with play framework, specs2 and withBrowser

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, integration-testing, specs2

I'm trying to create some integration level tests in play 2.3 using the browser with Fluentlenium. I'd like to run all the specification in the same application and with the same browser. What I got so far is

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpecification {
  override def is = args(sequential = true) ^
    "Testing some behavior" ^
    "When I go somewhere I should see something" ! f1 ^
    "Then when I fill in such form, I should create something" ! f2

lazy val app: FakeApplication = FakeApplication()
def f1  = new WithBrowser(webDriver = WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX), app = app) {
  browser.goTo("/")
  browser.$("a[href*='createsomething']").click();
  browser.url must equalTo("/login")
}

def f2 = new WithBrowser(webDriver = WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX), app = app) {
  browser.$("a[href*='createaccount']").click();
  browser.url must equalTo("/createaccount")
}
  }
```

The first test succeed, but then the second throws a configuration error (Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]) besides the browser is opened twice.

What's the recommended way of doing cucumber-like acceptance tests with Play Framework?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to instantiate only one webDriver?

Comment: It seems of no importance because I'm getting the same error in the second test